# Move screen up when keyboard appears to certain px or dp

Tags: android

I have editText on the top screen and some button on bottom of screen, so I need to make it so and edit text and button will visible when keyboard appears. I've tried to use android:windowSoftInputMode, but I still can see just part of button. How to move keyboard on certain px or dp value or bind it to certain view element?

Comment: Add your XML content in ScrollView it will fix the problem hopefully!

Comment: Can you show us some code. It sounds like you want to use a RelativeLayout for your EditText (which should be top aligned) and Button (which should be bottom aligned), and the AdjustResize windowSoftInputMode, which resizes your view to the remaining space between top and keyboard top.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this? 
`android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize"`